# Compose Destinations from ViewModel

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation, android-jetpack-compose-navigation

I use Compose Destinations library for navigation (but the question actually applies to any way of navigating).
And I want to avoid working with navigation in the composite functions that represent my screens. So I want to get rid of such code in my composable functions:

```
@RootNavGraph(start = true)
@Destination
@Composable
fun Welcome(
    navController: DestinationsNavigator,
    viewModel: WelcomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        viewModel.eventFlow.collect { event ->
            when (event) {
                is WelcomeViewModel.Event.NavigateToProfile -> {
                    navController.navigate(ProfileDestination)
                }
                /* other navigation events */
            }
        }
    }
    WelcomeView()
}
```

So my question is: how to Inject `navController: DestinationsNavigator` into some class (lets say `Navigator`) which will be Injected to my `ViewModel` so that I can do navigation directly from ViewModel. Something like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class WelcomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val navigator: Navigator
) : ViewModel() {

    /* some variables */

    fun onSomeAction() {
        /* do some calculations */
        navigator.navigateToProfile(param)
    }

    /* other functions */
}
```

I tried search for the solution but didn't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended.  But you can follow [this](https://github.com/raamcosta/compose-destinations/issues/306#issuecomment-1336196138) approach.

Comment: I do not need to inject DestinationsNavigator directly into ViewModel. I mean another class (Navigator, NavigationController, or doesn't matter how to name it), which maybe can handle the Activity lifecycle to avoid memory leaks. It can handle the flow of navigation events, so it must have an injected DestinationsNavigator. However, I do not understand how I can put DestinationsNavigator into such a class.